# Customizing Python logger with an extra dictionary field yields traceback for external modules with KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, logging, traceback

For my module I've defined a custom class logger:

```
class MyCustomLogger(Logger):
    def _log(self, level, msg, args, exc_info=None, extra=None):
        if not extra: # try intercepting extra not being set
            extra = {"class_name": "External Module"}
        super(MyCustomLogger, self)._log(level, msg, args, exc_info, extra)
```

I then use it in a class, `MyClassExample`:

```
from logging import getLogger, LoggerAdapter, setLoggerClass

from mymodule.loggerconfig import MyCustomLogger

class MyClassExample(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        setLoggerClass(MyCustomLogger)
        loggingName = "%s-%s-%s" % (self.__class__.__name__, self._property1, self._property2)
        self.logger = getLogger()
        self.logger = LoggerAdapter(self.logger, {'class_name': loggingName})
```

Then in my driver, I'd do:

```
$ cat driver.py
#!/usr/bin/python3 -tt -u

def setupLogging(name, scriptName):
    basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s: %(levelname)-8s {0}[%(process)d] %(class_name)s: %(message)s".format(scriptName), level=INFO)
    logger = getLogger()
    loggingHandler = SysLogHandler()
    logger.addHandler(loggingHandler)
    logger = LoggerAdapter(logger, extra)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scriptName = path.splitext(path.basename(argv[0]))[0]
    logger = setupLogging(__name__, scriptName)

    logger.info("%s version %s (library distribution version %s)" % (scriptName, __version__, packageVersion()))

    m = MyClassExample()
    m.methodA()
```

This works great if I want to log messages of my own inside `MyClassExample`.

However, all other modules I bring in with `import` that also want to log some messages, traceback with `KeyError` because they obviously don't have that `extra` `class_name` information:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/path/to/python/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 436, in format
    return self._format(record)
File "/path/to/python/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 432, in _format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'class_name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/path/to/python/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1081, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
File "/path/to/python/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 925, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
File "/path/to/python/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 667, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
File "/path/to/python/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 636, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
File "/path/to/python/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 438, in format
    raise ValueError('Formatting field not found in record: %s' % e)
ValueError: Formatting field not found in record: 'class_name'
```

So how can I satisfy logging format for the other modules while keeping my own custom format for the classes in my module?

Comment: Please show how you are setting the formatting.

Comment: In my opinion you should just use [structlog](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/) rather than trying to get stdlib logging to play ball here.